# ISO C++ forbids comparison between pointer and integer [-fpermissive]

Tags: c++, gcc

Проблема заключается в том, что код спокойно выполняется на онлайн gcc компиляторах и MSVS, а у меня - нет. 
Ошибку видит в строках `while (string[i] != '\0')` и ошибку`error: invalid conversion from ‘char’ to ‘char*’ [-fpermissive]` в строке `split_string[i] = '\0';`

gcc version 7.4.0

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdint>

#include <cstring>

#define MAXLEN UINT8_MAX

using namespace std;

void print(char** string)
{
    uint16_t i = 0;
    while (string[i] != '\0')
    {
        cout << string[i] << " ";
        i++;
    }
}

char** reverse_string(char** split_string, char* string)
{
    char temp;
    uint16_t counter = 0;

    char* token = strtok(string, " ");

    while (token != NULL)
    {
        split_string[counter] = token;
        counter++;
        token = strtok(NULL, " ");
    }

    for (uint16_t x = 0; x < counter; x++)
    {
        char* tempstr = split_string[x];
        uint16_t length = strlen(tempstr);

        for (uint16_t i = 0, j = length - 1; i < j; i++, j--)
        {
            temp = split_string[x][i];
            split_string[x][i] = split_string[x][j];
            split_string[x][j] = temp;
        }
    }

    return split_string;
}


int main()
{

    char string[MAXLEN];
    char* split_string[MAXLEN];

    for (uint16_t i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        split_string[i] = '\0';
    }

    cout << "Enter your words $ ";
    cin.getline(string, MAXLEN);

    char** reversed_string = reverse_string(split_string, string);

    cout << "Reversed string:   ";
    print(reversed_string);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Во-первых следует убрать из вопроса код, не относящийся к проблеме. Во-вторых не понятно, в чем тут проблема: зачем присваивать и сравнивать указатель с символьным литералом?

Comment: string у вас является указателем на указатель, следовательно   string[i]  это указатель, и  дальше...(см. комментарий выше)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Сравнение

```
string[i] != '\0'
```

это попытка сравнения значения *указателя* `string[i]` со значением `'\0'`. В С++98 `'\0'` являлся допустимой формой null-pointer constant, то есть в C++98 такое сравнение интерпретировалось как

```
string[i] != 0
// или
string[i] != NULL
```

Это обычное сравнение с null-указателем. С таким же успехом вы могли написать

```
string[i] != false
```

и этот код являлся бы корректным в С++98.

Но начиная с C++11 уже не разрешается использовать `'\0'` (или `false`) в качестве null-pointer constant и этот код является ошибочным.

Все то же самое относится и к присваиванию `split_string[i] = '\0'`

Comment: Спасибо за хорошее объяснение